# 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I m stuck at the error :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_network.py", line 239, in <module>
    demo()
  File "neural_network.py", line 227, in demo
    NN.train(X)
  File "neural_network.py", line 168, in train
    error += self.backPropagate(targets)
  File "neural_network.py", line 133, in backPropagate
    change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah(int), (self.ah.shape[0],1),dtype=int)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I m getting this error in my backPropagate function of neural network

```
   # update the weights connecting hidden to output
    change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah, (self.ah.shape[0],1),dtype=int)
            self.wo -= self.learning_rate * change + self.co * self.momentum 
            self.co = change 

    # update the weights connecting input to hidden
    change = hidden_deltas * np.reshape(self.ai, (self.ai.shape[0], 1),dtype=int)
            self.wi -= self.learning_rate * change + self.ci * self.momentum 
            self.ci = change
```

My MLP_NeuralNetwork class which I used to implement digit recognition looks like this  which has two main functions feedForward and backPropagate where feedForword is working fine but getting problem in backPropogate function:

```
class MLP_NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, input, hidden, output, iterations, learning_rate, momentum, rate_decay):
        # initialize arrays
        self.input = input + 1 # add 1 for bias node
        self.hidden = hidden
        self.output = output

        # set up array of 1s for activations
        self.ai = np.ones(self.input)
        self.ah = np.ones(self.hidden)
        self.ao = np.ones(self.output)
        input_range = 1.0 / self.input ** (1/2)
        self.wi = np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = input_range, size = (self.input, self.hidden))
        self.wo = np.random.uniform(size = (self.hidden, self.output)) / np.sqrt(self.hidden)
        self.ci = np.zeros((self.input, self.hidden))
        self.co = np.zeros((self.hidden, self.output))


    def feedForward(self, inputs):
        if len(inputs) != self.input-1:
            raise ValueError('Wrong number of inputs you silly goose!')
        self.ai[0:self.input -1] = inputs
        # hidden activations
        Z = np.dot(self.wi.T, self.ai)
        sum=np.add.reduce(Z)
        self.ah = tanh(sum)

        # output activations
        Z=np.dot(self.wo.T, self.ah)
        sum = np.add.reduce(Z)
        self.ao = sigmoid(sum)

        return self.ao


    def backPropagate(self, targets):
        if len(targets) != self.output:
        raise ValueError('Wrong number of targets you silly goose!')
        # calculate error terms for output
        # the delta tell you which direction to change the weights
        output_deltas = dsigmoid(self.ao) * -(targets - self.ao)

        # calculate error terms for hidden
        # delta tells you which direction to change the weights
        error = np.dot(self.wo, output_deltas)
        hidden_deltas = dtanh(self.ah) * error

        # update the weights connecting hidden to output
        change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah, (self.ah.shape[0],1))
        self.wo -= self.learning_rate * change + self.co * self.momentum 
        self.co = change 

        # update the weights connecting input to hidden
        change = hidden_deltas * np.reshape(self.ai, (self.ai.shape[0], 1))
        self.wi -= self.learning_rate * change + self.ci * self.momentum 
        self.ci = change

        # calculate error
        error = sum(0.5 * (targets - self.ao)**2)

        return error
```

ERROR I M GETTING IS :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_network.py", line 240, in <module>
    demo()
  File "neural_network.py", line 228, in demo
    NN.train(X)
  File "neural_network.py", line 169, in train
    error += self.backPropagate(targets)
  File "neural_network.py", line 134, in backPropagate
    change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah, (self.ah.shape[0],1))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I m not able to move forward due to this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the code shown here works. The code generating the error doesn't. The traceback shows `self.ah(int)` which is the source of error. The code below just has `self.ah` which is correct.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I tried that also what you have suggested just now but that too haven't solved my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

If `self.ah` is a floating point number or numpy array maybe you are trying to call it with an argument `int` here:

```
change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah(int), (self.ah.shape[0],1),dtype=int)
```

Since `self.ah` is not an object that you can call like this, you might be getting the error.

Also if you are missing a mathematical operator somewhere, that could cause this error as well (e.g. `x (y+z)` instead of `x*(y+z)`).

Comment: self.ah is a numpy array :
        self.ai = np.ones(self.input)
        self.ah = np.ones(self.hidden)
        self.ao = np.ones(self.output)
I changed to this # update the weights connecting hidden to output
        change = output_deltas * np.reshape(self.ah, (self.ah.shape[0],1))
        self.wo -= self.learning_rate * change + self.co * self.momentum 
        self.co = change 
And now getting error 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'
Can you suggest what to do now? If you say I can post my 300 lines of code also for that.

Comment: Maybe you can try to write `print(self.ah)` and see what type of variable you have as `self.ah` before you calculate `change`. Do you also update the values of `self.ah`?

Comment: print(self.ah) is printing 1.0 and I have posted my MLP_neural network class please have a look over it.

Comment: `Z=np.dot(self.wo.T, self.ah); sum = np.add.reduce(Z)` this operation might be resulting in a float rather than an array, problem might be that.

Comment: No that's not the case see the error i m getting its related with shape where no use of sum is there.

Comment: `self.ah` is the result of this sum. You say that it prints 1.0, thus a float. Float does not have a property called shape.